# Why is s3 event not trigger when having files without extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created s3 bucket and lambda function. I need to trigger lambda function when file upload to s3 bucket.I used S3 events. It's working fine when files having file extension.

But my issue is event not trigger when uploading files without file extension.
Lambda function created by using python 3.9
Do you have any idea to do this?

I added S3 trigger configuration suffix as *.* / .*.  All are not works

Or else is there a way to add a specific file extension in bucket side when uploading. I couldn't add file extension in my side. Because this upload is doing by AWS AppFlow through

***Update***
Below is the S3 event configuration currently having
[image]

Below are the S3 event triggered file names ( I have tried file names.)

1. **anyname.jpg**
2. **data.json**

Below is the file name I used without file extension. (For this file to event not triggered)

1. **data**

Comment: Why did you configure a **suffix**? Have you tried simply leaving it blank?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put it blank and tried. But not worked. That's why I added suffix.

Comment: And another thing I notices, my file contains json body, so I manually added file extension as json and tried. Then also not worked. After that I added suffix to .json. Then it workd.

Comment: It seems by default it's not getting json files. But without adding suffix and if I upload image file. Then it's working.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Something seems strange! You should not need to add a Suffix to make a trigger work. Please Edit your question to show a screenshot of the trigger configuration. Also, please include some examples of object keys (filenames) that worked, and those that didn't.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details. Question: How do you know that `data` did not trigger the event? How are you checking whether the Lambda function was triggered?

Comment: I have added logs in my code and I checked them in cloudwatch. Now I did a change, I created another lambda in nodejs 16.x. Then tried and saw it worked. Then after created another lambda with python 3.7 version , it also worked,

Comment: After that again tried old one, now it also working. Before create new lambda, today also I tried one time. On that time also not worked. No idea what happened. Anyway now it's working.Thank you so much for your replies and your time.